# What Is The Best Word Choice: Is, Are, Were, or Have Been

Tags: grammar, word-choice

The volume of letters that the United States Post Office processes ____ staggering.

A. Is
B. Are
C. Were
D. Have been

I think it would be A.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is A.

"The volume of" is considered singular, so only "is" works here.

The same would go for the following nouns (the ____ of): amount, area, weight, height, percentage, number, etc